Audio player won't play to previous song from an array of music
For the past week I've been coding this music website project, and my main goal is to make my own audio controller without using the HTML <audio> tag.

Instead, in JS, I made an object function called song() with properties such as name, creator, audio source, and image source (for the image cover of the audio controller). Then I made my own song objects from the function and put them in an array called songQue[] in the order of which song plays first and which plays last.

var themeToggle = document.querySelector(".themeToggle");
var playBtn = document.getElementById("playPause");
var skipForward = document.getElementById("playForward");
var skipBack = document.getElementById("playBack");
var progressBar = document.querySelector(".progressBar");
var scrubber = document.querySelector(".scrubber");
var coverImg = document.querySelector(".coverImg");
var songName = document.querySelector(".songName");
let isPlaying = false;

//object function
function song(name, artist, src, img) {
  this.name = name;
  this.author = artist;
  this.src = new Audio(src);
  this.img = img;
}

//objects
const onceInParis = new song(
  "Once In Paris",
  "Pumpupthemind",
  "once-in-paris-168895.mp3"
);
const forHer = new song(
  "For Her",
  "Liderc",
  "for-her-chill-upbeat-summel-travel-vlog-and-ig-music-royalty-free-use-202298.mp3",
  "https://cdn.pixabay.com/audio/2024/04/14/22-20-51-951_200x200.jpg"
);
const etheralVistas = new song(
  "Etheral Vistas",
  "Denys_Brodovskyi",
  "ethereal-vistas-191254.mp3",
  "https://cdn.pixabay.com/audio/2024/02/14/21-04-08-947_200x200.png"
);
const solitude = new song(
  "Solitude",
  "lucafrancini",
  "solitude-dark-ambient-electronic-197737.mp3",
  "https://cdn.pixabay.com/audio/2024/03/22/19-00-46-73_200x200.jpg"
);

const glossy = new song(
  "Glossy",
  "Coma-Media",
  "glossy-168156.mp3",
  "https://cdn.pixabay.com/audio/2024/03/04/18-30-15-842_200x200.jpeg"
);

//array of songs that'll be played
let songQue = [onceInParis, forHer, etheralVistas, solitude, glossy];

let currentIndex = 0;
let currentSong = songQue[currentIndex];

songName.textContent = currentSong.name;
coverImg.style.backgroundImage = currentSong.src;

//plays and pauses the audio
playBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (!isPlaying) {
    isPlaying = true;
    playBtn.setAttribute("name", "play");
    console.log("not playing");
    currentSong.src.pause();
    return;
  }
  if (isPlaying) {
    isPlaying = false;
    playBtn.setAttribute("name", "pause");
    console.log("playing!");
    currentSong.src.play();
    return;
  }
});


This isn't all of my code, just the code that's relavant to the problem

The song that's chosen to be played is based on the currentIndex. For example, since the current index is at 0 the song "Once In Paris" will played first. This is because the currentSong is based on the index of songQue[] that matches with currentIndex.
The audio controller has its own icon buttons that control how the music is played, like a pause/play button and the skip forward button that's used with the JS seen above. There are also the skipBack and skipForward buttons that move forward or back by 25 seconds.Here's there JS:

skipForward.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (currentSong.src.currentTime + 25 >= currentSong.src.duration) {
    currentSong.src.currentTime = currentSong.src.duration - 1;
  } else {
    currentSong.src.currentTime = currentSong.src.currentTime + 25;
  }

  moveProgress();
});


skipBack.addEventListener("click", function () {
  currentSong.src.currentTime = currentSong.src.currentTime - 25;
  moveProgress();

  if (currentSong.src.currentTime - 25 <= 0) {
    playBackAudio();
  }
});

function playNextAudio() {
  if (currentSong.src.currentTime >= currentSong.src.duration) {
    currentIndex++;

    if (currentIndex < songQue.length) {
      currentSong.src = songQue[currentIndex].src;
      currentSong = songQue[currentIndex];
      songName.textContent = songQue[currentIndex].name;
      coverImg.style.backgroundImage = `url('${songQue[currentIndex].img}')`;
      currentSong.src.duration = 0;
      console.log(currentIndex);
      console.log(currentSong);
      currentSong.src.play();
      moveProgress();
    } else {
      console.log("All songs have been played!");
    }
  }
}

function playBackAudio() {
      currentIndex--;

      if (currentSong.src.currentTime === 0) {

        currentSong = songQue[currentIndex];
        currentSong.src = songQue[currentIndex].src;
        songName.textContent = songQue[currentIndex].name;
        coverImg.style.backgroundImage = `url('${currentSong.img}')`;
        currentSong.src.duration = 0;
        console.log(currentIndex);
        console.log(currentSong);
        moveProgress();
        currentSong.src.play();
      }
      }

//checks if the function needs to be run
setInterval(playNextAudio, 300);

The skipBack button plays back a current song by 25 seconds, however, i've been trying to make it so if, when the button is pressed, causing the current song goes to all the way back to the beginning (0 seconds or somehow less) it begins playing the previous song (In other words, the previous item in songQue[] that's not being used as the currentSong).
I've tried to make a function called playBackAudio(). It works by subtracting the currentIndex by one and setting the currentSong to the new songQue[] object item based on the subtracted currentIndex.
For example, if the current song is "For Her" and the playBack button is clicked until the current time reaches back to 0, the previous song "Once In Paris" should be played. This is because the songQue index of "Once In Paris" is 0 (songQue[0]) while the index of "For Her" is 1 (sonQue[1]), and since this causes the function playBackAudio to run, the currentIndex goes from 1 to 0, therefore, it should make Once In Paris play.

skipBack.addEventListener("click", function () {
  currentSong.src.currentTime = currentSong.src.currentTime - 25;
  moveProgress();

  if (currentSong.src.currentTime - 25 <= 0) {
    playBackAudio();
  }
});


function playBackAudio() {
      currentIndex--;

      if (currentSong.src.currentTime === 0) {

        currentSong = songQue[currentIndex];
        currentSong.src = songQue[currentIndex].src;
        songName.textContent = songQue[currentIndex].name;
        coverImg.style.backgroundImage = `url('${currentSong.img}')`;
        currentSong.src.duration = 0;
        console.log(currentIndex);
        console.log(currentSong);
        moveProgress();
        currentSong.src.play();
      }
      }


It resulted in everything but the audio itself changing back based on the previous song object. In other words, when going from "For Her" back to "Once In Paris" the song title and cover changed but the audio was still playing "For Her".

Can you share a working example? JSFiddle, StackBlitz...
